# AutoCompleteTextView for contacts with input value as projectionArgs value + filtering contacts only with phone numbers

Tags: android, android-sqlite

Im making AutoCompleteTextView for contacts, value for selectionArgs field I get from user input ( letters to match with contact names) how do i add another filter( 1 more projectionArgs or something in query selection ) so i can see contacts only that have numbers (ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER + " = 1" ) not contacts only with email.

```
static final String[] CONTACTS_SUMMARY_PROJECTION = new String[]{
        ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME,
        ContactsContract.Contacts._ID,
        ContactsContract.Contacts.PHOTO_THUMBNAIL_URI,
        ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER
};
cursorLoader = new CursorLoader(getApplicationContext(), ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, CONTACTS_SUMMARY_PROJECTION,
                    ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME + " LIKE ?", new String[]{"%" + value + "%"},null);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i wonder, is it works only for me or other noticed same situation, when I can't find the answer, I just ask question and then, almost instantly find that answer  by myself :) 
all i needed was that line in selection :

```
 + " AND " + ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER + " = 1"
```

whole query :

```
cursorLoader = new CursorLoader(getApplicationContext(),
                    ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, CONTACTS_SUMMARY_PROJECTION,
                    ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME + " LIKE ?"
                     + " AND " + ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER + " = 1",
                    new String[]{"%" + value + "%"},
                    null);
```

if you know better solution to this , please add , i'm very new to SQLite for Android